# Perl for Windows - how to allow user input date range for Gmail email adresses extractor script

Tags: perl

I got this perl script from  http://blog.mekk.waw.pl/archives/47-Scrap_email_addresses_from_GMail_inbox_or_other_folder.html

I am able to run it on Windows with ActiveState Perl.

I had never done programming in perl before, but now I'm in situation need to modify the script to suit my needs.

I need to allow user to be able to pass date range, so only email addresses at that date ranges will be extracted. Eg, user would able to run it this way to extract email addresses from messages dated Feb 01, 2014 until Feb 28, 2014:

c:>extractor.pl --login=abc@gmail.com --password=MyPassW --folder=INBOX  --begindate=20140201 --enddate=20140228

I found similiar script that support date range at http://ulrith.livejournal.com/484386.html but I have no idea how to combine them.

Thank you for your help!

```
package Gmail::ExtractEmails;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;
use Mail::IMAPClient;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use Email::Address;
use Encode qw(decode encode);
use Text::CSV_XS;

with 'MooseX::Getopt';

has 'folder'  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => "INBOX",
                  documentation => "GMail folder to scan (by default INBOX, use --list-folders to check which folders are available)");
has 'csv' => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', predicate => 'has_csv',
              documentation => "Name of created .csv file. Printing to stdout if not set");
has 'host'  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Str', default => "imap.gmail.com",
                documentation => "GMail IMAP hostname (default imap.gmail.com, change if you are using some port mapping or tunelling)");
has 'port'  => (is => 'ro', isa => 'Int', default => 993,
                documentation => "GMail IMAP port (default 993, change if you are using some port mapping or tunelling)");
has 'verbose' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Bool', default => 0);
has 'list-folders' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Bool', default => 0, accessor => 'list_folders',
                       documentation => "Just print names of all known folders instead of running normally");
has 'login'   => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1,
                  documentation => "GMail username (either \"SomeBody\@gmail.com\", or \"SomeBody\")");
has 'password' => (is => 'rw', isa => 'Str', required => 1,
                   documentation => "GMail password");

has '_imap' => (is => 'ro', builder => '_build_imap', lazy => 1, init_arg => undef, predicate => '_has_imap');

sub DEMOLISH {
    my $self = shift;
    if($self->_has_imap) {
        $self->_imap->logout;
    }
}

sub _build_imap {
    my $self = shift;

    printf STDERR "Connecting to GMail as %s at %s:%s\n", $self->login, $self->host, $self->port
      if $self->verbose;

    my $socket = IO::Socket::SSL->new(
        Proto => 'tcp',
        PeerAddr => $self->host,
        PeerPort => $self->port);

    my $imap = Mail::IMAPClient->new(
        Socket => $socket,
        Server => $self->host,
        Port => $self->port,
        User => $self->login,
        Password => $self->password,
        Uid => 1,
       )
      or die "Gmail connection failed: $@\n";

    unless($imap->IsAuthenticated()) {
        #use Data::Dumper; print Dumper($imap->Report);
        die "Gmail authorization failed. Check your username and password.\n";
    }
    printf STDERR "... succesfully connected to GMail\n", $self->login
      if $self->verbose;

    return $imap;
}

sub run {
    my $self = shift;

    if($self->list_folders) {
        my $folders = $self->_imap->folders or die "Can't read folders list: " . $self->_imap->LastError . "\n";
        print "Known folders:\n    ", join("\n    ", @$folders), "\n";
        exit(0);
    }

    # Uniquifying emails. email -> label -> count
    my %emails;

    $self->_imap->select($self->folder);
    #my $messages = $self->_imap->fetch_hash("RFC822.HEADER"); # legacy
    #my $messages = $self->_imap->fetch_hash("BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO CC)]"); # all in one string,
    my $messages = $self->_imap->fetch_hash(
        "BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)]",
        "BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (TO)]",
        "BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (CC)]"
       );

    foreach my $msg_id (keys %$messages) {
        my $msg_data = $messages->{$msg_id};
        foreach my $key (keys %$msg_data) {
            my @addresses = $self->get_addresses_from_email_field($msg_data->{$key});
            foreach my $a (@addresses) {
                #print STDERR "Found $a->{email} ($a->{label}) in $msg_id\n"
                #  if $self->verbose;
                $emails{ $a->{email} }->{ $a->{label} } += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
        binary => 1, always_quote => 1, auto_diag => 2,
    });

    my $csv_fh;
    if($self->has_csv) {
        open $csv_fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", $self->csv or die "Can't create " . $self->csv . ": $!\n";
    } else {
        open($csv_fh, ">>&STDOUT") or die "Can't rewrite stdout\n";
        binmode($csv_fh, ":encoding(utf8)");
    }

    $csv->combine("E-mail Address", "Name");
    print $csv_fh  $csv->string, "\n";

    foreach my $email (sort keys %emails) {
        $csv->combine($email, grep {$_} sort keys %{$emails{$email}});
        print $csv_fh $csv->string, "\n";
        #print $email, ": ", encode('utf8', join(", ", sort keys %{$emails{$email}})), "\n";
    }

    close $csv_fh or die "Can't save " .  $self->csv . ": $!\n";

    if($self->has_csv) {
        print "Saved to ", $self->csv, "\n"
          if $self->verbose;
    }
}

sub get_addresses_from_email_field {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    $text = decode('MIME-Header', $text);   # decode =?UTF-8?... and such
    $text =~ s/[ \r\n]*\Z//;   # strip trailing newlines
    $text =~ s/[ \r\n]+/ /;    # normalize separators to one space
    my @addresses;
    if($text =~ /\A(?:From|To|Cc|CC): *(.*)\Z/s) {
        @addresses = Email::Address->parse($1);
    }
    if($text && ! @addresses) {
        warn "Could not find any sensible address in the following email header:\n$text";
    }

    return map { { email => $_->address, label => $_->phrase || '' } } @addresses;
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;

###########################################################################
# Main
###########################################################################

package main;
use Getopt::Long::Descriptive; # enforce sensible help
use Getopt::Long;
Getopt::Long::Configure("auto_help");

my $app = Gmail::ExtractEmails->new_with_options();
$app->run();
```

Comment: Can I suggest you start by learning some perl. Eg look  at http://learn.perl.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl script that will do what you are asking for:

http://www.athensfbc.com/public/scrape_addrs

./scrape_addrs -S host/user/pwd -m mailbox -a after_date -b before_date

For example:

./scrape_addrs 
      -S imap.gmail.com:993/user/password
      -m Inbox 
      -a 24-feb-2014 
      -b 28-feb-2014

The output looks like this:

========================================
date    26-Feb-2014 23:07:17 +0000
from    "Google+" <noreply-66910ff2@plus.google.com>
to      rfs@gmail.com
cc      tom@xyz.net
========================================